# Filtering by multiple properites without using custom filter?

Tags: angularjs

Basically I need to filter through a list, requiring each item to have multiple matching properties.

I want to filter my products to only display those with a matching category AND subcategory (both needs to match).

The following does not work (subcategories are being disregarded):

```
<div ng-repeat="p in vm.products | filter: {category: vm.category.name, subcategoryy: vm.subcategory}">
```

I know I could write a custom filter but before doing so I wanna make sure there's no way to do it without writing a custom filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<div ng-repeat="p in vm.products | filter: {category: vm.category.name} | filter: {subcategoryy: vm.subcategory}">`

also: subcategoryy? or subcategory?

Comment: Ahh I'm an idiot!
Didn't see the double "y".
Thanks a lot though!

Comment: second set of eyes can be invaluable